# WP Sql query multiple where clause

Tags: wpdb, sql

I'm trying to get the users that have registered after a specific time (this case $today) and who have the newsletter field true and the account false.
This is what I have so far but the result is always 0.

```
$new_users_newsletter = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->users
    RIGHT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta
    ON $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id
    WHERE ($wpdb->users.user_registered >= '$today'
        AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'newsletter' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'true'
        AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'account' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'false')
    GROUP BY $wpdb->users.ID"
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with `WP_User_Query` instead:

```
$args = array (
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'newsletter',
            'value' => 'true',
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'account',
            'value' => 'false',
        ),
    ),
    'date_query'    => array(
        array(  
            'after'     => '2015-01-13 00:00:00',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),          
     ),
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

where I assume your user meta values are *boolean* strings, i.e. `'true'` and `'false'`.